# Tomcat 7.0.27 fails to start after dropping TomEE war

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee

I have a Tomcat 7.0.27 installation that works perfectly fine. However, after dropping the file tomee-plus-webapp-1.5.2.war in my webapps folder (following the instructions provided here: http://tomee.apache.org/installation-drop-in-war.html) the server starts but gives me this exception when I try to access it through a web browser:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspSourceDependent
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:343)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

This is the error I find in the logs:

```
sep 19, 2013 10:00:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [applicationSocketServlet] en el contexto con ruta [/tomee] lanzó la excepción [La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción] con     causa raíz
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:     org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet.createWebSocketInbound(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/catalina/websocket/StreamInbound;
at org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet.doGet(WebSocketServlet.java:125)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When I remove the tomEE war from my webapps folder, everything works fine again.

Any ideas on what could be happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess this is problem in Netbeans. Does the server start properly if you start it with `catalina start` command?

Comment: Netbeans just calls the start command from what I know. Only if the problem is the deploy from netbeans, but the start would not change.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Probably it starts something more also (some monitor for debugging?) as it is in the stack trace.

Comment: Propably, but its not related to the `start` command, As I use netbeans and don't even have the start command, and still can debug and deploy with it.